# extending jsDoc to handle custom tags

Tags: node.js, documentation-generation, jsdoc3

I'm looking to extend jsdoc (particularly with docstrap). I have a nodeJS application and want to split the jsdoc navigation to Controllers, Views ,etc. 
I've managed up to a certain extent with this by creating my custom tags such as `@controller` and managed to get it to be capturaed by JsDoc similar to `@module` so it generates the page (with description) . However my issue is when it comes to the functions associated with for example the controller which are located with a 'module.exports' function. The documentation generated basically ignores any other functions in that @controller file. How can i capture these function.

Below is an example of this:

```
/**
 * @controller my_controller
 */
module.exports = {
    /**
     * @description my function
     */
    myFn : function(){

    }
}
```

Comment: so far the only way i have gotten this to work is by using the `@memberof controller:my_controller` . any other options?

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me in a similar context is to use a plugin which effectively tags the element as a `module` when it is tagged as `controller`. That way you get the module-like behaviour and then when rendering the modules you simply exclude the models, view and controllers.

I have to patch a lot of places to get it to work otherwise as some behaviours are simply bound to `modules` and there is no abstraction on top which would allow you to trigger the same behaviours.

Comment: can you share your config maybe?